# MySQL select takes 0.2 sec; equivalent UPDATE takes 1.5 minutes!

Tags: mysql

This query runs in 0.2 seconds and finds 9 rows:

```
SELECT S.id, S.frame, S.active,
  GF.groupNum, GF.frameDesc
FROM skus S 
  INNER JOIN group_frames GF ON (GF.frame = S.frame)
WHERE GF.groupNum = 204 AND GF.frameDesc LIKE '%lumbar%';
```

This query runs in 1.5 *minutes* and updates the same 9 rows:

```
UPDATE skus S
  INNER JOIN group_frames GF ON (GF.frame = S.frame)
SET S.active = 0, S.updated_by=101355, updated_at = NOW()
WHERE GF.groupNum = 204 AND GF.frameDesc LIKE '%lumbar%';
```

... while this incredibly-hackish version runs in 0.5 seconds and updates the same rows:

```
UPDATE skus S SET S.active = 0, S.updated_by=101355, updated_at =
NOW() WHERE S.id IN (   SELECT id FROM (    SELECT S1.id    FROM skus S1 
        INNER JOIN group_frames GF ON (GF.frame = S1.frame)     
WHERE GF.groupNum = 204 AND GF.frameDesc LIKE '%lumbar%' ) S3)
```

*(using a dummy inner-query to defeat the query-optimizer complaining about the same table being used in a FROM clause)*

Why on earth did the second query take so long?!

Comment: include `EXPLAIN {query}` information. Also Include 'SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`. Which MySQL version?

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: MySQL won't EXPLAIN an Update query ... at least, mine won't.  Oh well, the question is now theoretical because Query #3, and the much cleaner variation suggested below by Lennart in answer #1, does solve the issue and let me get on with my day.  "But ... WTF?!"  I sure would like to know what `EXPLAIN` would have said, because these tables aren't particularly gigantic ... a few thousand rows each ... and the server that's running them is quite beefy.

Comment: As noted in the answer below, Lennart's answer actually takes two minutes to run, also!  Danged if I know why, because the `WHERE EXISTS` query completes almost instantaneously, as expected.)  At this point, I have utterly **no** idea what the heck MySQL is doing . . . I think I'd call it a bug.

Comment: You were asked to show `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for both tables and your MySQL version. Where is this data? Where is `EXPLAIN {query}`, for the queries for which you can do it at least? And add the into about records amount in each table. *I think I'd call it a bug.* If you do not understand something about MySQL, then this bug is not necessarily a bug **of MySQL**...

Comment: You have an old version of MySQL.  `JOINs` in `UPDATE` were not as efficient in that version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your question, but you might try a regular update like:

```
UPDATE skus S
    SET S.active = 0
      , S.updated_by=101355
      , S.updated_at = NOW()
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM group_frames GF 
    WHERE GF.frame = S.frame
      AND GF.groupNum = 204 
      AND GF.frameDesc LIKE '%lumbar%'
);
```

Indexes like:

```
CREATE INDEX ... ON skus (frame);
CREATE INDEX ... ON group_frames (groupNum, frame, frameDesc);
```

will probably help

Comment: That `WHERE EXISTS ... SELECT 1` trick is a very nice variation and a lot cleaner than the hack I had to come up with (query #3).  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Now isn't **THIS** interesting ... that variation takes every bit as long as my Query #2, even though it sure doesn't look like it should!  It took two minutes!  (But the inner query, in the `WHERE EXISTS` clause, completed almost instantaneously, as expected, when run by itself.)  *"Curiouser and curiouser!"*

Comment: Gee, it sure would be interesting if I *could* `EXPLAIN UPDATE...`  This is just plain goofy.

Comment: What indexes do you have?